# vba - Average on all rows except which contains min date

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to write a vba code to calculate the average of a numeric column (third one), but excepting the row that contains the min date, because I want to compare the first-day data against the other days' data.

However, I also have to consider the year. I want to average all AN16 apart from AN17.

I have no idea how to do this and nothing here seems to work for me.

Here is my data:

```
AN17    01-mar-17   65298340734
AN17    02-mar-17   30382114732
AN17    03-mar-17   25149388406
AN17    04-mar-17   54249361285
AN17    05-mar-17   34757947426
AN17    06-mar-17   18546884324
(I need an average here, that excludes number from March 1st)
AN16    26-feb-16   56450549777
AN16    27-feb-16   51285706203
AN16    28-feb-16   37384621464
AN16    29-feb-16   28992655707
AN16    01-mar-16   21979700006
AN16    02-mar-16   27826026350
(I need an average here, that excludes number from February 26th)
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks and best regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a Office 365 Excel subscription then use this formula in D1:

```
=IF(A1<>A2,AVERAGEIFS(C:C,A:A,A1,B:B,">" & MINIFS(B:B,A:A,A1)),"")
```

And copy down:

[image]

---

If you do not have access to the Office 365 then use this formula instead:

```
=IF(A1<>A2,AVERAGEIFS(C:C,A:A,A1,B:B,">" & AGGREGATE(15,6,$B$1:$B$12/($A$1:$A$12=A1),1)),"")
```

---

IF you are using 2007 or older then you will need to use this array formula:

```
=IF(A1<>A2,AVERAGEIFS(C:C,A:A,A1,B:B,">" & MIN(IF($A$1:$A$12=A1,$B$1:$B$12))),"")
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.